# What commands other than open() are there in python that edit files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

Are there any other commands than open() in python to edit files (on Windows or *NIX).

Comment: `open` is the primary way to get a file descriptor, and pretty much all the mainstream ways of I/O are built on that.  What else did you have in mind?

Comment: You don't "edit" files in  a programming language. You read and write to files. So what you mean with "edit" is unclear.

Comment: why do you need something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this kind of information very fast and interactively if you're using [ipython](http://ipython.org/):

```
In [5]: file. #[tab pressed]
file.close       file.isatty      file.read        file.tell
file.closed      file.mode        file.readinto    file.truncate
file.encoding    file.mro         file.readline    file.write
file.errors      file.name        file.readlines   file.writelines
file.fileno      file.newlines    file.seek        file.xreadlines
file.flush       file.next        file.softspace   

In [5]: print file.flush.__doc__
flush() -> None.  Flush the internal I/O buffer.

In [6]:
```

but I still recommend checking the [documention](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), section 7.2.

Also, to construct a file object (get an object of type 'file'), "open" is the only possibility in python3 (in python2 there is also "file", which is sort of alias to "open")